# Clear DropDown when Cell is cleared

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

with the help of a tutorial i made a script with dependent drop downs. I tried to modify it that when a  cell in Column A is cleared/modified the first level of the drop down too.

```
var mainWsName = "master";
var optionsWsName = "options";
var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(mainWsName);
var wsOptions = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(optionsWsName);
var options = wsOptions.getRange(2, 1,wsOptions.getLastRow()-1,2).getValues();

function onEdit(e){
  var activeCell = e.range;
  var val = activeCell.getValue();
  var r = activeCell.getRow();
  var c = activeCell.getColumn();
  var wsName = activeCell.getSheet().getName();
  if(wsName == mainWsName && c == 2 && r > 3){
    if(val === ""){
      ws.getRange(r, 3).clearContent(); 
      ws.getRange(r, 3).clearDataValidations();
    } else {
      ws.getRange(r, 3).clearContent(); 
      var filteredOptions = options.filter(function(o){ return o[0] === val });
      var listToApply = filteredOptions.map(function(o){ return o[1] });
      var cell = ws.getRange(r, 3); 
      applyValidationToCell(listToApply,cell);
    }
  }  
}

function applyValidationToCell(list,cell){
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp
  .newDataValidation()
  .requireValueInList(list)
  .setAllowInvalid(false)
  .build();
  cell.setDataValidation(rule);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Explanation:

- The direct way to solve your issue is to add one more `if` condition to check whether the value of the cell in column `A` is empty. If it is empty, then remove both data validations and the existing values. If not, then create them:

  ```
  if(wsName == mainWsName && ws.getRange(r,1).getValue()==''){
      ws.getRange(r, 2,1,2).clearContent(); 
      ws.getRange(r, 2,1,2).clearDataValidations();
  } 
  else {
      var listToApply = options.map(o=>o[0]);
      var cellB = ws.getRange(r, 2); 
      applyValidationToCell(listToApply,cellB); 
  }
  ```

### Complete solution:

```
var mainWsName = "master";
var optionsWsName = "options";
var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(mainWsName);
var wsOptions = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(optionsWsName);
var options = wsOptions.getRange(2, 1,wsOptions.getLastRow()-1,2).getValues();

function onEdit(e){
  var activeCell = e.range;
  var val = activeCell.getValue();
  var r = activeCell.getRow();
  var c = activeCell.getColumn();
  var wsName = activeCell.getSheet().getName();

  
  // new code starts here
  if(wsName == mainWsName && ws.getRange(r,1).getValue()==''){
      ws.getRange(r, 2,1,2).clearContent(); 
      ws.getRange(r, 2,1,2).clearDataValidations();
  } 
  else {
      var listToApply = options.map(o=>o[0]);
      var cellB = ws.getRange(r, 2); 
      applyValidationToCell(listToApply,cellB); 
  }
  // new code ends here

  if(wsName == mainWsName && c == 2 && r > 3){


    if(val === ""){
      ws.getRange(r, 3).clearContent(); 
      ws.getRange(r, 3).clearDataValidations();
    } else {
      ws.getRange(r, 3).clearContent(); 
      var filteredOptions = options.filter(function(o){ return o[0] === val });
      var listToApply = filteredOptions.map(function(o){ return o[1] });
      var cell = ws.getRange(r, 3); 
      applyValidationToCell(listToApply,cell);
    }
  }  
}

function applyValidationToCell(list,cell){
  
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp
  .newDataValidation()
  .requireValueInList(list)
  .setAllowInvalid(false)
  .build();
  
  cell.setDataValidation(rule);
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much Marios! I tried with the IF but wrapped it arround the existing IF. Which didn´t work. Also i tried to bring it in to the IF Attribute. Thanks again i carry on training myself.

Comment: @diGga glad it was helpful to you :) Happy coding :)